# Memory sizes (in bytes) of vector iterator, vector chain, and vector flatten in Rust

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, flatten, chaining

I have the following example code:

```
let vector_1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
let vector_2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

{ 
  let vector_1_iter = vector_1.iter(); 
}
{ 
  let chained = vector_1.iter().chain(vector_2.iter());
}
{
  let vector_combined = vec![vector_1, vector_2];
  let flatten = vector_combined.iter().flatten();
}
```

I want to know the sizes of vector_1_iter, chained, flatten in bytes. If I was finding the sizes of vector_1 and vector_2, I would just take the length of the vector and multiply it by the bytes of i32. However, I'm not sure whether the size would change after converting the vector into an iterator. Same with chaining and flattening, would they not take up the same size equal to the entire length of the array times the size of each data type?

Comment: Why do you need the sizes? Also, *"I would just take the length of the vector and multiply it by the bytes of i32"* is incorrect. That's just the memory of the content; there is some control structure around it which takes (to my knowledge) `3*usize` of space. And there might be padding that is lost. Technically, not even that is true, the actual **size** of a vector is its **reserved** size, which does not necessarily need to match its content. As you can see: it's complicated.

Comment: [`std::mem::size_of()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) can help you get _some_ of the information, but it won't tell you the _total_ size including heap allocations, and definitely not any allocator overhead. **If you [edit] your question to tell us what you want to use the number for, perhaps we can give you a decent answer.**

Comment: If you're interested in heap allocations, might want to have a look at valgrind's massif or some [ad hoc techniques](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/small-strings-in-rust#profiling-memory-allocations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Size of Vec

[`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) is a struct, made up of a pointer to an area of memory allocated on the heap, a capacity (showing the total number of items which could be stored in the heap memory, and a length (showing the number of items that are currently stored in the heap memory).

Each of these is of type `usize` - which occupies 8 bytes on an x86_64 architecture.

Therefore the total memory occupied by a `Vec<i32>` is actually 24 bytes + (capacity x 4). Or, more generally:

```rust
std::mem::size_of::<Vec<T>>() + vector_1.capacity() * std::mem::size_of::<T>()
```

### Size of iterator

Note that this:

```rust
let vector_1_iter = vector_1.iter();
```

does not actually convert vector_1 into an iterator - `iter` borrows the vector, and returns a [std::slice::Iter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) which references it. It doesn't have any extra heap allocation associated with it, we can see it's memory size like this:

```rust
println!("size of vector_1_iter {}", std::mem::size_of::<std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>>());
```

The result is 16 bytes, on my machine.

### Size of chained iterators

When we use `chain` to chain together two iterators, both of the iterators are consumed, and a `std::iter::Chain` is returned. We could use `size_of` again, but this starts to get a little more tricky to express when there are multiple levels of generic parameters. Instead we can use [std::mem::size_of_val](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html):

```rust
let chained = vector_1.iter().chain(vector_2.iter());
println!("size of chained iter {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&chained));
```

On my machine this prints `32` - which makes sense, since it is housing both of the original iterators (each of which was 16 bytes).

### Flattened Iterator

We can use the same method:

```rust
let vector_combined = vec![vector_1, vector_2];
let flatten = vector_combined.iter().flatten();    
println!("size of flattened iter {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&flatten));
```

This prints `48` for me.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1a8fe2cb4a458bbfbc7f25e55eee79a)

---

Note that none of the iterators above consumed the original containers they were iterating over. If you had used [`into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_iter) the result would be quite different, because this method consumes the `Vec` and returns an `IntoIter` struct - so it then owns the heap memory which contains the actual contents of the `Vec`.

Also note that the contents and layout of these structs are implementation details, so you can't really rely on these sizes being constant. `Vec` is a bit of an exception, because there are some [guarantees](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees) made about its structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response! When finding the memory size of the Iter slice, how come we don't pass the iterator in the argument of size_of anywhere? For the chained iterator and flattened iterator, we pass a reference in the argument of size_of_val, but we don't pass a reference for the vector_1_iter? How come?

Comment: You could use `size_of` or `size_of_val` in either case. The former just needs to know the type and does not need an argument, while the latter infers the type from the argument. `size_of_val` is easier to use if you have the value and the type is hard to express (as it would be for a compound iterator like `Chain`).